# WPF: How to embed button inside text flow (wrap text around button)?

Tags: wpf, button, flowdocument, word-wrap, wrappanel

I'd like an advice to the following problem: I want to embed a `Button` into a text flow, but when I embed a `Button` and `Label` (or `TextBlock`) into the `WrapPanel`, I get the first figure:

[alt text http://sklad.tomaskafka.com/files/wpf-wrappanel-problem.png](http://sklad.tomaskafka.com/files/wpf-wrappanel-problem.png)

I think that one of solutions could be `FlowDocument`, but I feel that this is far too heavy for a control simple like this (which could be used in several hundred instances). Do you have some other ideas about how to implement this? Thank you!

EDIT:
One solution could be the following (I didn't know it was possible to put more stuff into `TextBlock`), but I would lose the ability to bind (which I need):

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <Span>
        <Button x:Name="MyButton" Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}" Content="+" />
        <Run x:Name="MyLabel" Text="{Binding Path=Subject}" />
        <!--
        Problem: binding makes following error:
        A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Text' property of type 'Run'. 
        A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.
        -->
    </Span>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that implementing BindableRun correctly is pretty tricky - and almost all other available implementations will cause an exception from wpf layouting engine when the bound content changes from null to something non-null - see [this problem, keyword "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7743e9a2-3ffa-44ba-aa88-1b2214461b88/)

Corrrect implementation from Microsoft is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569761.aspx) - it shows how tricky this really is.

Answer (score 1):

To bind to Run.Text, checkout the [BindableRun](http://fortes.com/2007/03/bindablerun/) class by Fortes.  Simple to implement, I use it all over my projects.

Comment: LOL, I found this 5 minutes ago and just implemented a solution with that :)). Thanks anyway :).

Comment: I found that implementing BindableRun correctly is pretty tricky - yours (and almost all other available implementations) will cause an exception from wpf layouting engine when the bound content changes from null to something non-null.

Corrrect implementation from Microsoft is here - but really tricky http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569761.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Solution: [BindableRun](http://fortes.com/2007/03/bindablerun/) class + the following markup:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Button x:Name="MyButton" Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}" Content="+" />
    <common:BindableRun x:Name="Subject" BindableText="{Binding Path=Subject}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing it works on the designer of a UserControl...
In that case, using the Property Change of your control to set the value to the Run is enough. I mean, if you had something like:

```
<TextBlock>          
   <Run Text="{Binding ElementName=thisCtrl, Path=Description}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Then just name the run, and on your property change handler of your UserControl DependencyProperty get/set the value.